# How to use COALESCE in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is it possible to use COALESCE in laravel query?

```
$multipleitems = DB::table('votes')
    ->select('masterItemId',DB::raw('sum(votes) as voteSum'))
    ->whereBetween('voteDate',array($startDate,$endDate))
    ->where($condition)
    ->groupBy('masterItemId')
    ->get();
```

In the above code I want to get each item and its total votes. If there is no vote I want to get '0'.

But in the above code it returns items that have atleast one vote. Is there any method to get this done in laravel?

Comment: Does the votes table hold the actual votes that were casted or an overall number per item the users can vote on?

Comment: Actually the votes table contains following fields
-"Id,
userId,
masterItemId,
Votes,
voteDate,"-.
the vote filed contains either 1 or -1. and i wants to get the total votes of each items.

Comment: So you want also `masterItemsId`'s that have no votes as well? For which there are no entries in the `votes` table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the OP was not too helpful, but I will give it a shot! I assume, that the `votes` table contains actual votes cast by users on the items. This means, that if an item did not receive any vote, then that item id (`masterItemId`) does not exist in the `votes` table.

This means that the votes table has to be left joined on the main items table on the `masterItemId` field. I will call the main items table: `items`, and assume that it has an `itemId` field that matches the `masterItemId` field in the `votes` table.  In SQL terms:

```
select items.itemId, ifnull(sum(votes.votes),0) as votesSum
from items left join votes on items.itemId=votes.masterItemId
where votes.voteDate between ... and ... and <other conditions>
group by items.itemId
```

I'm not familiar with Laravel, but you will need something like this, however do not treat is as copy-paste code:

```
$multipleitems = DB::table('items')
                 ->leftJoin('votes','items.itemId','=','votes.masterItemId')
                 ->select('items.itemId',DB::raw('ifnull(sum(votes.votes),0) as voteSum'))
                       ->whereBetween('votes.voteDate',array($startDate,$endDate))
                       ->where($condition)
                       ->groupBy('items.temId')
                       ->get();
```

Comment: Hopes this answer will help me.But i just wants to know is there any scope of using mysql COALESCE in laravel.i have many uses of this function in my another queries.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can use coalesce() instead of ifnull().