# how to change my query into laravel eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have query like this :

```
SELECT 
t1.id as id_guru, t1.nama_guru,
COALESCE(t2.total, 0) AS total
FROM `guru` t1
LEFT JOIN(SELECT id_guru, COUNT(*) as total FROM absensi_guru where status_masuk = "Terlambat" GROUP BY id_guru) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_guru
```

and i want to change my query into laravel Eloquent ORM, i tried so many way from this site and even in laracast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I will create a View in MySQL with the Query you have and then use Eloquent or Query Builder in Laravel to query the DB.

In case, If you want directly in Laravel, without view, you need to define Eloquent relationships. You may find more information about eloquent relationships [HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

To use in Laravel, here is an example code, just do not do copy-paste, understand it and update your query

```
$multipleitems = DB::table('items')
             ->leftJoin('votes','items.itemId','=','votes.masterItemId')
             ->select('items.itemId',DB::raw('ifnull(sum(votes.votes),0) as voteSum'))
                   ->whereBetween('votes.voteDate',array($startDate,$endDate))
                   ->where($condition)
                   ->groupBy('items.temId')
                   ->get();
```

Here is the [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675277/coalesce-in-laravel)

Comment: no no, i tried my query on Mysql(PHPMyAdmin) and work so fine, even i tried to change my query into Eloquent ORM, i think my relationship is right, but i always get error in this one : `COALCASE(t2.total,0)` because in my table, it didn't have `total` field

Comment: @DarkCode999 if this help, please accept it as correct answer (Green Mark under the up-down arrows, on answer).