# How to replace the value of field on another?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have some table with the same two fields:

`value, default_value`

How to return result with replacing `value` on `default_value` when value is null?

I dont use iteration with result collection. I try to make universal solution.

I tried to use local scopes, but seems it is bad decision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [COALESCE in laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675277/coalesce-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eloquent, you can create accessor like this:

```
public function getRealValueAttribute() 
{
   return $this->value ? $this->value : $this->default_value;
}
```

and assuming you get results like this:

```
$items = Model::all();
```

you can display this field for models like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo $item->real_value;
}
```

Comment: And how to call accessor?

Comment: May be `getValueAttribute() ` without Real?

Comment: @Garaman Rather not, as it's the same as `value` and it might cause some confusion if you need to use the plain value, so I would recommend you to use other name.